# CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: database, postgresql

I am working on AWS server + PostgreSQL. When I execute a query for creating the database I get an error:

```
CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
```

I am working on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The query itself would make a be very helpful addition to question. From the message alone I can only assume that you try to create a database in a Transaction. If so your database creation logically belongs before the transaction.

Comment: Hi, I am very new to postgraSQL. I am first time start with postgraSQL. I have searched for same error, but the last two days I am facing this issue. Your comment is quite difficult for me to understand.

Comment: "*How can I resolve this issue?*" - turn *on* autocommit. How you do that depends on the SQL client you are using.

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your valuable comment. I have to turn on autocommit and that create command is working.

Answer (score 19):

I have used turn on autocommit in PostgreSQL and it's working for me.

Here is the query to turn on the autocommit

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT = ON
```

**Note** that this only works for **PostgreSQL 9.4 and below**

Comment: In DBeaver go to "Edit connection" (F4) and tick the autocommit-on checkbox

Comment: That parameter hasn't done anything for a long time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40546968/2850543

Comment: @MillieSmith that is not correct. The link you referred to is talking about a client library deprecating a parameter in its own API. Postgres supports setting autocommit behavior. Here is the current documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html

Comment: This is not relevant from PostgreSQL 9.5 onwards

Comment: Referring to other answer - such option deprecated since Postgres 7.4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517942/unrecognized-configuration-parameter-autocommit-in-postgresql-nodejs

Comment: I'd strongly recommend the option below - 9.4 is ancient at this point and you are probably doing something like the drop and create option, so you need the \set option in the next answer.

Comment: Why it's necessary to enable autocommit to create a database? It'd be great to have deeper explanation in this answer

Comment: Thanks @redacted you saved some head banging time.

Answer (score 11):

Note, for postgres 9.5+ you have to use:

```
psql -c '\set AUTOCOMMIT on'
```

---

But I'm going to guess, that what you really wanted to do is destroy the database and recreate it in a single command. Here you go:

```
printf '\set AUTOCOMMIT on\ndrop database <your_db_here>; create database <your_db_here>; ' |  psql postgres
```

Answer (score 6):

With psql you can also run drop and and create your database in one command by using multiple `--command` arguments:

```
psql postgres -c "drop database if exists <your_db_here>;" -c "create database <your_db_here>;"
```

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres SQL 14.1, pgAdmin query tool, I see this same error when running the create database query with other queries. Running the create database query by itself completes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to execute PostgreSQL scripts in a **python** program like this:

```py
with psycopg2.connect(
   dbname=database, host=server, port=port, user=user, password=password
) as connection:  
    connection.autocommit = True
```

what solved the issue for me it that I changed it to:

```py
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    dbname=database, host=server, port=port, user=user, password=password
) 
connection.set_isolation_level(psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
```