# unrecognized configuration parameter "autocommit" in PostgreSQL NodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

> {"message":"Err on translation create, for key blah blah blah
>   ","name":"SequelizeDatabaseError","stack":"SequelizeDatabaseError:
>   unrecognized configuration parameter \"autocommit\"\n    at
>   Query.module.exports.Query.formatError
>   (/var/www/courses/courses.com.mm/dist/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:361:16)\n
>   at Query.
>   (/var/www/courses/courses.com.mm/dist/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/query.js:79:21)\n
>   at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at Query.emit (events.js:188:7)\n
>   at Query.handleError
>   (/var/www/courses/courses.com.mm/dist/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:108:8)\n
>   at Connection.
>   (/var/www/courses/courses.com.mm/dist/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:171:26)\n
>   at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at Connection.emit
>   (events.js:188:7)\n    at Socket.
>   (/var/www/courses/courses.com.mm/dist/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:109:12)\n
>   at emitOne (events.js:96:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)\n
>   at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)\n    at
>   Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)\n    at TCP.onread
>   (net.js:543:20)","parent":{"name":"error","length":102,"severity":"ERROR","code":"42704","file":"guc.c","line":"5692","routine":"set_config_option","sql":"SET
>   autocommit =
>   1;"},"original":{"name":"error","length":102,"severity":"ERROR","code":"42704","file":"guc.c","line":"5692","routine":"set_config_option","sql":"SET
>   autocommit = 1;"},"sql":"SET autocommit =
>   1;","isOperational":true,"level":"info","timestamp":"2016-11-09T16:56:44.885Z"}

I've encountered above error when I checked log file by terminal. I'm not sure it's postgresql error or something else. Please help me how to solve it. And here is my postgresql version:

> PostgreSQL 9.5.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2
>   20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit (1 row)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The configuration parameter `autocommit` has been disabled since version 7.4, released in 2003.

Up to PostgreSQL version 9.4 the parameter was still present, but had no effect.

From PostgreSQL 9.5 on (released in January 2016), the parameter has been removed, and trying to set it will cause an error message.

Try to update your client software to a more recent version.

Comment: OK, then how *do* I disable autocommit? Because it needs to be disabled to properly use a fetch size: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: It is no problem to disable autocommit *on the client*.

Comment: Right, I see. Back to getting jOOQ/JDBC in line then. Thanks.