# Executing Transaction control procs in PG-promise (Autocommit)

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I have a proc like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "TRY-DQ-7a28fd25d95c0969bff16b963af1c832"()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
 DECLARE "Continue" boolean :=True; 
 BEGIN
 COMMIT;
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE READ WRITE;
    INSERT INTO test1 (a) VALUES (i);
    IF i % 2 = 0 THEN
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        ROLLBACK;
    END IF;
COMMIT;
 END 
 $$;
```

Which i want to execute using PG-promise ,whats different is this proc requires autocommit ON to execute correctly atleast on pgAdmin how do i achieve the same in pg-promise? or the driver below it?

**UPDATE:**

This seems to be bug in PG/Or something that i am misunderstanding (This was surfaced via pg-promise so first i thought this was something to do with it)

Setup:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP"(n integer)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
 BEGIN
 FOR i IN 0..n LOOP
    COMMIT;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE READ WRITE;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE "x" (i integer) ON COMMIT DROP;
 END LOOP;
 END 
 $$;
```

pg-promise invocation:

```
setInterval(() => {
    pgWriter.any(`
    DO 
    $$
    BEGIN
    CALL "SP"(10);
    END 
    $$;`)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
}, 1000);
```

OR
pgAdmin invocation:

```
DO 
$$
BEGIN
CALL "SP"(10);
END 
$$;
```

**Results**: The very first invocation fails with following message (*Only First*) run it again on the same connection it will normally execute.

```
ERROR:  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL must be called before any query
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE READ WRITE"
PL/pgSQL function "Q"."SP"(integer) line 5 at SET
SQL statement "CALL "Q"."SP"(10)"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at CALL
SQL state: 25001
```

**Analysis** : So far i am thinking it should be a problem in my code maybe they are setup something one the run first time which helps them to run it multiple times later (some state), also interestingly 2 lines seems to be important

1. `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE READ WRITE;`
2. `CREATE TEMP TABLE "x" (i integer) ON COMMIT DROP;`

If either of them is commented the error goes away..

If community knows anything about this or point error in my code will really help Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pg-promise` simply executes your queries. So a better question would refer to the actual SQL that you want executed. Also, I do not see any value in a stored procedure doing multiple inserts like that, which can be done more efficiently without any procedure.

Comment: This is just sample, the logic inside the SP is more complex, i understand when you say pg-promise helps you to execute queries, the thing that i am asking is for the setting in pg-promise which can make autocommit on or off just like what pgAdmin or psql provides, cause the above SP works only when autocommit is on.. so need the right setting for it in pg-promise

Comment: You are looking for something that does not exist. There is no such thing as auto-commit on/off, it's just pgAdmin feature that automatically opens a transaction before executing your procedure, and then commits it in the end. You need to ask the right question, in terms of what SQL you want executed. There is no auto-commit feature on/off in pg-promise, because there cannot be.

Comment: Strictly, speaking, PostgreSQL does allow configuration of the `AUTOCOMMIT` flag, but I'm pretty sure this is not what you are looking for here.

Comment: I think that is what exactly these apps are changing, even psql and not only pgAdmin so i gathered its a feature exposed by driver or something is that not correct?

Comment: No, the driver just executes queries. If you want to change the `AUTOCOMMIT` flag automatically `ON`, or `OFF`, that's just another query, it is not a separate feature. But normally, you do not touch that flag. It is an odd design to start changing that flag. I think there's some design misunderstanding or flaw that you are looking at.

Comment: Scrap that, I checked, `AUTOCOMMIT` was a legacy that's not even supported anymore by PostgreSQL. So, you need to figure out what is it you want executed in terms of SQL, before any further advise can be given. And again, as far as `pg-promise` is concerned, it just executes queries.

Comment: I think in normal case 99% you wont require it, but in my case its SP which needs to control transaction level and this is where things are fuzzy in PG as well but one thing i have verified for sure that the same query works when Autocommit is set to ON, so was wondering if there were any settings for it as i thought it to be some driver level function can you paste the sql command for setting this on and off..

Comment: I already explained, `AUTOCOMMIT` is no longer supported by PostgreSQL, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517942/unrecognized-configuration-parameter-autocommit-in-postgresql-nodejs). You are asking the wrong question.

Comment: Saw that comment now, ok let me add more details post my RnD Thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you've helped a lot in the past ;) any idea what this guy here is looking for?

Comment: Maybe you just want to execute the procedure while inside a transaction, just guessing. In that case, see [transactions](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#transactions). Then it is trivial.

Comment: I have posted an update, It has nothing to do with pg-promise or auto commit i was on wrong track there, pg-promise helped to uncover this as it only happens once when the connection is fresh. Thanks vitaly-t for help so far

Comment: There is definitely something odd going on inside your procedure. As I suggested earlier - try invoking the procedure from inside a transaction, maybe that will shed some light. I cannot advise anything better presently.