# SQL pgAdmin 4 Syntax

Tags: sql, syntax-error, pgadmin

Trying to run code and I keep getting "syntax error at or near "CREATE"".[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdC27.png)

This code is from "Practical SQL" by Anthony DeBarros. After installing PostgreSQL and pgAdmin, I tried executing this code and it keeps popping up with this error. Not sure what is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: did you miss a semicolon (`;`) after the `autocommit = on`? also, post the sql command as text not screenshot.

Comment: oh, also, that `autocommit` is removed on postgresql 9.5 and later, [see QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40546968). just ditch it for less headache.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed some semicolon (**;**) after
`set autocommit = on`

Change it to
`set autocommit = on; CREATE DATABASE analysis;`

and I think it will work, inform me if this helped, please.