# ansible cannot execute SQL CREATE DATABASE CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block

Tags: database, postgresql, ansible, transactions

There are several entries that [CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482777/create-database-cannot-run-inside-a-transaction-block) which give the answer autocommit needs to be on. However, they do not reference ansible which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [specific `postgresql_db` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/postgresql_db_module.html) that will take care of your db creation (or removal/dump/restoration) and will manage [idempotency](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#desired-state-and-idempotency) out of the box.

```yaml
- name: Create database if needed
  postgresql_db:
    name: "{{ dbname }}"
    state: present
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to Ansible and find myself thinking in older forms, such as querying the database directly. I appreciate you pointing this out so I can learn more ways to use Ansible.

Answer (score 1):

I found in the [anisble documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/postgresql_query_module.html) there is a way to turn autocommit on such as:

```yaml
- name: create database if needed
  postgresql_query:
    autocommit: yes
    query: |
      CREATE DATABASE {{ dbname }}; 
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
```

I thought this would be helpful for people like me who tend to look at stack overflow first when searching for help. Note: `{{ dbname }}` is a variable. You could also use a literal.

Comment: It's good you found how to turn on autocommit if you need it in other situation. Meanwhile, this is probably a good example of [the xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Your real question IMO is "How to create a postgresql database from ansible". And I have given an answer to that. Side note: this should also teach you that you should read docs before diving in SO.